# Page redirection works in Chrome and Safari but not in FireFox

Tags: javascript, angular, paypal

I have an angular2 app. I have integrated PayPal sandbox for testing online payment in it and it works fine in Safari and Chrome but not in Firefox.

Here is the issue -

After my request is approved by PayPal, I redirect the page to their Payment page.

**donate-component.ts** -

```
this.paypalService.makePaymentRequest(500, 'http://' + rootUrl + '/event/1/home').subscribe(data => { 
    window.location.href = data.json.links[1].href;
})
```

**paypal-api-service.ts** -

```
makePaymentRequest(amount: number, redirectUrl: string) {
    var headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.TOKEN);

    var options = new RequestOptions({
        headers: headers
    });
    var body = JSON.stringify({
        "intent": "sale",
        "redirect_urls": {
            "return_url": redirectUrl,
            "cancel_url": "http://example.com/your_cancel_url.html"
        },
        "payer": {
            "payment_method": "paypal"
        },
        "transactions": [
            {
                "amount": {
                    "total": amount,
                    "currency": "USD"
                }
            }
        ]
    });
    var requestoptions = new RequestOptions({
        method: RequestMethod.Post,
        url: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/',
        headers: headers,
        body: body
    })
    return this.http.request(new Request(requestoptions))
        .map((res: Response) => {
            if (res) {
            return { status: res.status, json: res.json() }
            }
    }).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Here the URL in `data.json.links[1].href` is something like - https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=XXXXX#/checkout/login.

This works as expected in Safari and Chrome. But in firefox it just refreshes my page. I do see a bar at the bottom that briefly says '**waiting for sandbox.paypal.com**'but within a second the page refreshes.

I have tried the redirection with `window.location.replace()` also, but it doesn't work.

**EDIT:**

This works in FireFox on windows but not on Mac.

Comment: Can you expand your code a little bit. What are you doing after this subscribe? Anything related with a page reload?

Comment: Not doing anything after subscribe. Don't know if its relevant but I have added the code of makePaymentRequest(). I am passing a redirect URL to the PayPal API. After successful payment, PayPal redirects my page to the URL that I pass to it.